# what is normal for a site to use in terms of cpu and memory

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, memory, cpu

We have a few sites running MVC3 on a windows 2008 server. We're seeing that in average these sites are using over 300 mb in memory each one, and high CPU. Each site easily goes to 20-25% CPU when they get requests.

Is this normal?
I know my question is very general, but if we were to spend time on optimization, etc.. what should we aim for? what is considered normal in terms of memory and cpu usage for a typical database driven MVC3 website?

Also, I was told that we should "profile" the application to troubleshoot the high CPU usage? Is this done via Visual Studio, or through some other tools?

thanks for your help in advance,

G.S

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the details of your application and what it's doing, it's impossible to say what's normal and what isn't. If performance is a problem, you should optimize, if it isn't, you shouldn't :)

Profiling is a general term for measuring the performance of different aspects of your application. You can *profile* memory, cpu usage, garbage collections and thread use (among other things) using a *profiler*.

There are several profilers around such as [Ants](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/), [.Net memory profiler](http://memprofiler.com/) and some [excellent ones built into visual studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx). They are available in the pro versions of VS2012 and up.